# OSError in python

Tags: python, pygame

I get this error when I run my program:

> OSError: unable to read font file 'C:\Users\Büşra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\freesansbold.ttf'

I'm a beginner in pygame. My code like this:

```
mainfont=pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",18)
```

Comment: Maybe the file is just corrupted. Are you sure it is valid font file?

Comment: Are you sure that the file is located in *"C:\Users\Büşra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pygame"*

Comment: Yes, I sure. What can I do? Should I put it in to the desktop ?

Comment: Probably there is an issue with those two special characters in your path (`üş`)? Try to move the file to a path without special characters and specify in python the exact path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that this part of the directory: `C:\Users\Büşra`, is the problem.

Python, and other programming languages and their libraries do not react well to unicode text, can can very well lead to errors.

What I would recommend is putting the font file [`.fon` or `.ttf`] in the same directory as the game or script and referencing it like this:

```
example = pygame.font.Font('./myfont.ttf', size)
```

That should work.